# Fourier transform clustering

Tags: clustering, fourier-transform

Which clustering algorithm would you use, moreover which distance measure, in case of analysis in frequency domain?

I would like to perform Discrete Fourier Transform on time series and perform clustering, but I'm not sure what to use in case of frequency spectra. I could use K-means with Euclidean distance as distance measure, but on the other hand I could use K-medoids and a different distance measure. I'm not able to find any information what is usually done in practice in such a case.

Comment: Some papers on the topic:   https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nin/papers/AmitBioMedSigProcJan09.pdf,  https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/wics.1444,           https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1467-9892.2011.00758.x,

Answer (score 1):

If you consider/convert the frequency spectrum to be a kind of histogram, all the distributional and divergence measures can be used. Also, quadratic forms and earth mover's distance (EMD) may be an option.
They can't be used with k-means, but with many other algorithms.